# Find biggest concatenation word in array

Tags: c#, concatenation

I'm new to C#, can someone help me understand why my code doesnt work?
Seems like there something wrong with variable `word` which needs to be returned, but I don't understand what.

```
public virtual bool concatOnly()
        {
            int tmp = 0;
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                tmp += word.Length;
            }
            return (tmp <= word.Length);
        }
```

I also don't really understand what I need to do in this:

```
 public virtual void removeRepeat()
        {
            IEnumerator<string> iterator = words.GetEnumerator();
            string checkWord = null;
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                checkWord = iterator.Current;
                foreach (string tmpWord in words)
                {
                    if (tmpWord.Contains(checkWord) && checkWord.Length < tmpWord.Length)
                    {
                        iterator.Remove();
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

[Here's my full code](http://goo.gl/f8pK4Y)

Comment: Couldyou clarify exactly what doesn't work?

Comment: 'word' conflicts with the declaration 'Concatenation.Concatenation.ConcatWord.word' have this error for the first block of code

Comment: It's very important that you also post the error messages you are getting.  One of the error messages is `main.cs(76,32): error CS0135: `word' conflicts with a declaration in a child block`.  I'll post a fix for that error as an answer.

Comment: @Vaik Please following the convention and use pascal-case for your function names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 3**
In order to fix the second compile error (see Update 2), you need to remove from the list without doing so via Iterator, which has no remove method.  One way would be the following, which saves up the indexes for removal after traversal by the iterator.  Note that I remove the indexes in reverse order, so that the index numbers to be removed are not changed by prior removals.

```
public virtual void removeRepeat()
{
    IEnumerator<string> iterator = words.GetEnumerator();
    string checkWord = null;
    List<int> removeIndexes = new List<int>();

    int i = -1;
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        checkWord = iterator.Current;
        i++;
        foreach (string tmpWord in words)
        {
            if (tmpWord.Contains(checkWord) && checkWord.Length < tmpWord.Length)
            {
                removeIndexes.Add(i);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    removeIndexes.Reverse();
    foreach(var index in removeIndexes) {
        words.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

After fixing the first compile error (see my original answer below, which now works), your code is still giving this compile error `main.cs(90,38): error CS1061: Type`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator' does not contain a definition for `Remove' and no extension method`Remove' of typ
e `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator' could be found.

**Update**

I've changed my original answer to something that at least compiles. What I did is to change the original `return (tmp <= word.Length);` back to using `word`, which is the class member variable, not the local variable.

**Original**

Change the name of variable `word` in method `concatOnly()`:

```
public virtual bool concatOnly()
{
    int tmp = 0;
    foreach (string w in words)
    {
        tmp += w.Length;
    }
    return (tmp <= word.Length);
 }
```

This is because your class `ConcatWord`, of which `concatOnly` is a member method, already has a member variable named `word`: `internal string word;`.

FYI, the above shows that you also need to post the full code for the class ConcatWord.  It's fine to give the link to the full code that you provided, that can be helpful, but everything required to reproduce the error also needs to be present in your question here at SO.

Comment: `w` wouldn't be in scope where you return would it?

Comment: I think I may need *moar caffeination*!

Comment: Actually, this is way broken.  Trying to figure out if it can be salvaged.

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I can't figure out what it's supposed to do -

Comment: I think I understand it now--t took me a while.

Comment: @vaik, I've updated my answer to also solve the second compile error.

Comment: @DWright, thank you too much, my code almost work fine.